# Display Different Number of <li> Per Row

Tags: html, css, magento, layout, html-lists

I would like to make first row of  to have 3 products and second row 2 products and this pattern repeats.

Here is the code

```
 <ul class="products-grid products-grid--max-<?php echo $_columnCount; ?>-col">
<?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); // value 3 ?>
       <?php $i=0;$k=1;foreach($products as $product ?>
        <li class="item <?php echo ($k==4) || ($k%10==0)? 'big ': '' ?> <?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
         <?php echo $product->getName() ?>
         <?php $k++;?>
        </li>
    <?php endoforeach; ?>
    </ul>

<style>
    .big,.big img
    {
        width: 60% !important;
        height: 278px !important;
    }

</style>
```

The big class applies to 4th, 10th,14th,20th... `<li>` to make second row with 2 products. Now the problem is third `<li>` in the second row takes entire row and pushing down the next `<li>` to next row.

Screen shot link http://i59.tinypic.com/jjr4vc.jpg

This is magento and the product list scss file for reference.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
// This mixin outputs the styles to allow for grids with more than 3 columns
@mixin product-grid($column-count, $container-width, $class-append:"") {

    // Allow this mixin to be used for more specific purposes, such as grids contained within widgets
    @if $class-append != "" {
        $class-append: -#{$class-append};
    }

    /* Config: Columns + flexible gutter */
    $column-gutters: ($column-count) - 1;
    $container: $container-width - (2 * $trim);
    $column-width: ($container - ($column-gutters * $product-column-spacing)) / $column-count;

    /* Undo three-column config */
    .products-grid--max-#{$column-count}-col#{$class-append} > li:nth-child(odd) {
        clear: none;
    }
    .products-grid--max-#{$column-count}-col#{$class-append} > li:nth-child(3n+1) {
        clear: none;
    }
    .products-grid--max-#{$column-count}-col#{$class-append} > li:nth-child(even),
    .products-grid--max-#{$column-count}-col#{$class-append} > li:nth-child(3n) {
        margin-right: percentage($product-column-spacing / $container);
    }

    /* Set column config */
    .products-grid--max-#{$column-count}-col#{$class-append} > li {
        margin-right: percentage($product-column-spacing / $container);
    }
    .products-grid--max-#{$column-count}-col#{$class-append} > li {
        width: percentage($column-width / $container);
        margin-right: percentage($product-column-spacing / $container);
    }
    .products-grid--max-#{$column-count}-col#{$class-append} > li:nth-child(#{$column-count}n+1) {
        clear: left;
    }
    .products-grid--max-#{$column-count}-col#{$class-append} > li:nth-child(#{$column-count}n) {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is confusing. First you say that the second row has two products, and then you say the problem is with the third item in the second row. So what is it? Edit: if the problem is that you want styles that counteract the SCSS you show, I'd say get rid of this SCSS and simply make the styles yourself, using `nth-child(5n)` and `nth-child(5n+3)`.

Answer (score 0):

Following script was worked for me.

```
<ul class="products-grid products-grid--max-<?php echo $_columnCount; ?>-col">
<?php $i=0; $k=$_columnCount; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
<?php 
$class="";
if($i%$k == 0){ $class='big'; }
$i++;
if($i==$k){ $i=0; $k--; }
if($k == 0) { $k=$_columnCount;$i=0; }
?>
<li class="item <?php echo $class;?><?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
<?php echo $product->getName() ?>
</li>
<?php endoforeach; ?>
</ul>

<style>
.big    {
Clear:both;
/*width: 60% !important;
height: 278px !important;*/
}
</style>
```

Hope this help you.